# Must the angle bisectors of a triangle all intersect at a common point- proof?

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

How could you informally write a proof, proving that all the angle bisectors intersect at one common point in a triangle?

Comment: [Like this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578316/bisectors-of-an-angle-in-a-triangle-intersect-at-a-single-point-proof-verifica)

Comment: @NormalHuman:  unfortunately, we can't close this as a duplicate as the other does not have an upvoted answer.  The question contains the answer.  I'll put an answer-please upvote.

Comment: Please don't use "proof-theory" tag; it does not mean what you think it means. Usually, no "proof" tag is needed at all: specifying the topic of question is enough.